# How do I convert "2012-03-02" into unix epoch time in C?

Tags: c, datetime, date, time

A string "2012-03-02" representing March 2nd, 2012 is given to me as an input variable (char *).

How do I convert this date into unix epoch time in C programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C (POSIX) provides a function for this. Use [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strptime.html) to convert the string into a `struct tm` value. You can then convert the `struct tm` into `time_t` using [`mktime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/mktime.html).

Comment: That's not standard, C, it's POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

Local time or UTC? If it's UTC, the easiest way to do the conversion is to avoid the C time API entirely and use the formula in POSIX for seconds since the epoch:

```
tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 + tm_yday*86400 +
    (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
    ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
```

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15

If it's local time, the problem turns into hell due to the fact that `time_t` is not guaranteed to be represented as seconds since the epoch except on POSIX systems, and the fact that it's difficult to compute a `time_t` value corresponding to the epoch (`mktime` will not work because it uses local time). Once you compute the `time_t` for the epoch, though, it's just a matter of using `mktime` for the time value you parsed and then calling `difftime`.

Comment: `tm_year` is current year - 1900.

Comment: What about doing `results=results-tm_gmtoff` to readjust by using the time zone offset? I think it is not a completely standard C (rather a extension), but I have tested it right now and it seems to be working OK.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: If you have tm_gmtoff you almost surely have a POSIX superset and then you have better more portable solutions via POSIX.

Comment: Is there any other formula/source where instead of tm_yday, I can use tm_mon and tm_mday?

Comment: @Gow: Yes, it requires some arithmetic with number of days in each month though. Perhaps open it as a new question if you want details, referencing this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67532995/how-to-convert-date-into-epoch-timestamp-using-the-tm-mday-and-tm-mon-in-formula

Answer (score 3):

Extract the pieces with an `sscanf`, populate `struct tm` (from `<time.h>`) with the data extracted, and finally use `mktime` to convert it to `time_t`.

```
time_t ParseDate(const char * str)
{
    struct tm ti={0};
    if(sscanf(str, "%d-%d-%d", &ti.tm_year, &ti.tm_mon, &ti.tm_day)!=3)
    {
        /* ... error parsing ... */
    }
    ti.tm_year-=1900
    ti.tm_mon-=1
    return mktime(&ti);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell why we need to subtract 1900 and 1 from tm_year and tm_mon ?

Comment: Because in `struct tm` years start with 1900, and the month is 0-based. You find all the relevant information about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Read it into a `struct tm` and call `mktime` to get your `time_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t epoch;
    char timeString[80] = { "05 07 2021 00 33 51" }; 
    struct tm my_tm;
    char buffer[80];

    memset(&my_tm, 0, sizeof(my_tm));
    if (sscanf(timeString, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &my_tm.tm_mon, &my_tm.tm_mday, &my_tm.tm_year, &my_tm.tm_hour, &my_tm.tm_min, &my_tm.tm_sec) != 6)
    {
        /* ... error parsing ... */
        printf(" sscanf failed");
        return 1;
    }
    my_tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    my_tm.tm_year -= 1900;
    my_tm.tm_mon -= 1;

    epoch = mktime(&my_tm);
    if (epoch == -1) {
        printf("Error: unable to make time using mktime\n");
    }
    else {
        strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", &my_tm);
        printf("%s  (epoch=%ld)", buffer, (long)epoch);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Note: This code convert the input you provided to "Fry May 7 00:33:51" and epoch=1620340431 which is not the one you mention in comment (Running under Win10 with MSVC)