# Converting string date to epoch time not working with Cython and POSIX C libraries

Tags: python, date, pandas, cython, epoch

I have a very large pandas dataframe and I would like to create a column that contains the time in seconds since the epoch for a ISO-8601 format date string.

I originally used the standard Python libraries for this but the result is quite slow. I have tried to replace this by using the POSIX c library functions `strptime` and `mktime` directly but have not been able to get the right answer for the time conversion.

Here is the code (to be run in an IPython window)

```
%load_ext cythonmagic

%%cython
from posix.types cimport time_t
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
import time
cdef extern from "sys/time.h" nogil:
    struct tm:
        int tm_sec
        int tm_min
        int tm_hour
        int tm_mday
        int tm_mon
        int tm_year
        int tm_wday
        int tm_yday
        int tm_isdst
    time_t mktime(tm *timeptr)
    char *strptime(const char *s, const char *format, tm *tm)
cdef to_epoch_c(const char *date_text):
    cdef tm time_val
    strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%d", &time_val)
    return <unsigned int>mktime(&time_val)
cdef to_epoch_py(const char *date_text):
    return np.uint32(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%d")))
cpdef np.ndarray[unsigned int] apply_epoch_date_c(np.ndarray col_date):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, n = len(col_date)
    cdef np.ndarray[unsigned int] res = np.empty(n, dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in range(len(col_date)):
        res[i] = to_epoch_c(col_date[i])
    return res
cpdef np.ndarray[unsigned int] apply_epoch_date_py(np.ndarray col_date):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, n = len(col_date)
    cdef np.ndarray[unsigned int] res = np.empty(n, dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in range(len(col_date)):
        res[i] = to_epoch_py(col_date[i])
    return res
```

The struct created by `strptime` does not look right to me the hours, minutes and seconds values are way too big, removing them or setting them to 0 does not seem to get the answer I'm looking for.

Here is a small test df which shows the values are not right for the c method:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
test = DataFrame({'date_text':["2015-05-18" for i in range(3)]}, dtype=np.uint32)

apply_epoch_date_py(test['date_text'].values)
Output: array([1431903600, 1431903600, 1431903600], dtype=uint32)
apply_epoch_date_c(test['date_text'].values)
Output: array([4182545380, 4182617380, 4182602980], dtype=uint32)
```

I don't get why the values for the c version are not always the same and so far off what they should be. I hope the mistake is reasonably small because the time difference between these two on a large dataframe is substantial (I'm not sure how much less work the c version is doing now as it is not working as expected)

```
test_large = DataFrame({'date_text':["2015-05-18" for i in range(int(10e6))]}, dtype=np.uint32)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 apply_epoch_date_py(test_large['date_text'].values)
Output: 1 loops, best of 1: 1min 58s per loop
%timeit apply_epoch_date_c(test_large['date_text'].values)
Output: 1 loops, best of 3: 5.59 s per loop
```

I have looked up this cython time.h [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533293/how-to-call-time-from-time-h-with-cython-i-cant-get-it-to-work) and a general c unix time from string creation [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542278/how-do-i-convert-2012-03-02-into-unix-epoch-time-in-c) which may be useful to someone answering.

My main question therefore is about the function `to_epoch_c` why is this function producing incorrect values? Thanks

Update:

The method from @Jeff is indeed the fastest and simplest approach to solving this problem using pandas.

The performance of the strptime/mktime in Python in poor in comparison to the other methods. The other Python based method mentioned here is much faster. Running the conversion for all the methods mentioned in this post (plus `pd.to_datetime` with string format given) provides interesting results. Pandas with infer_datetime_format is easily the fastest, scaling very well. Somewhat unintuitively if you tell pandas what the date format is it is much slower.

[image: Performance Comparison]

Profile comparison of both pandas methods:

```
%prun -l 3 pd.to_datetime(df['date_text'],infer_datetime_format=True, box=False).values.view('i8')/10**9
352 function calls (350 primitive calls) in 0.021 seconds
Ordered by: internal time
List reduced from 96 to 3 due to restriction <3>

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.013    0.013    0.013    0.013 {pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime}
    1    0.005    0.005    0.005    0.005 {pandas.lib.isnullobj}
    1    0.001    0.001    0.021    0.021 <string>:1(<module>)

%prun -l 3 pd.to_datetime(df['date_text'],format="%Y-%m-%d", box=False).values.view('i8')/10**9
109 function calls (107 primitive calls) in 0.253 seconds

Ordered by: internal time
List reduced from 55 to 3 due to restriction <3>

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.251    0.251    0.251    0.251 {pandas.tslib.array_strptime}
    1    0.001    0.001    0.253    0.253 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.252    0.252 tools.py:176(to_datetime)
```

Comment: Interestingly it works if you pass a time with the string

Comment: Thanks Padraic... adding `%H:%M:%S` to the format string and a `00:00:00` to the input text does indeed produce the correct unix time value. I'll leave this open in case somebody knows why it doesn't work with the shortened date format.

Comment: No worries, I will see if I can find the reason why, the good news is it runs in  12us vs 72us on your small input data

Comment: In C, you should probably initialize the struct explicitly: `tm time_val = {0};`. Have you tried to compare time performance of various Python variants? For example, `d = date(*map(int, "2015-05-18".split("-")))` and then [`timestamp = (d - date(1970,1,1)).days*DAY`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279) (`d` is treated as UTC date here even if it is not true for your input; it allows you to restore the original date from the timestamp (it can't be said about `mktime()` (that accepts a local date) -- it may fail for some dates in some timezones and its behavior might be OS dependent).

Comment: I got :`TypeError: Expected a mapping, got set` when I tried to init the struct using that syntax, I presume that doesn't work in Cython. As per Padraic's answer setting the struct hour, mins and secs fields individually did work though. The alternative Python method you provided is much faster than the strptime/mktime combination I was using as you can see in the performance plot.

Comment: @dsimmie: Use `@` syntax if you want me to be notified about your comment. And yes, `{0}` has a different meaning in C and Python (Cython in this case) -- the intent is to set all struct fields to zero ("In C" in the beginning and the semicolon ";" strongly hint that I meant the meaning that is used in C). In Cython, you probably have to initialize each element of the `tm` structure manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems if you don't pass in `time_val.tm_hour,  time_val.tm_min` and `time_val.tm_sec` the date is parsed incorrectly, setting the values to `0` will return the correct timestamp:

```
cdef extern from "sys/time.h" nogil:
    struct tm:
        int    tm_sec   #Seconds [0,60].
        int    tm_min   #Minutes [0,59].
        int    tm_hour  #Hour [0,23].
        int    tm_mday  #Day of month [1,31].
        int    tm_mon   #Month of year [0,11].
        int    tm_year  #Years since 1900.
        int    tm_wday  #Day of week [0,6] (Sunday =0).
        int    tm_yday  #Day of year [0,365].
        int    tm_isdst #Daylight Savings
    time_t mktime(tm *timeptr)
    char *strptime(const char *s, const char *format, tm *tm)
cdef to_epoch_c(const char *date_text):
    cdef tm time_val
    time_val.tm_hour,  time_val.tm_min,  time_val.tm_sec= 0, 0, 0
    strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%d", &time_val)
    return  <unsigned int>mktime(&time_val)
```

If you `print(time.strptime(date_text,  "%Y-%m-%d"))` you see python has the values set to `0` if you don't pass them to strptime:

```
 time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=12, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=138, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Setting the values to a default of `0` in `to_epoch_c` also returns `0`:

```
{'tm_sec': 0, 'tm_hour': 0, 'tm_mday': 18, 'tm_isdst': 1, 'tm_year': 115, 'tm_mon': 4, 'tm_yday': 137, 'tm_wday': 1, 'tm_min': 0}
```

If you don't set them in returns random timestamps because there seem to be various values for `tm_sec` etc..:

```
 {'tm_sec': -1437999996, 'tm_hour': 0, 'tm_mday': 0, 'tm_isdst': -1438000080, 'tm_year': 32671, 'tm_mon': -1412460224, 'tm_yday': 0, 'tm_wday': 5038405, 'tm_min': 32671}
{'tm_sec': -1437999996, 'tm_hour': 4, 'tm_mday': 14, 'tm_isdst': 0, 'tm_year': 69, 'tm_mon': 10, 'tm_yday': 317, 'tm_wday': 5, 'tm_min': 32671}
{'tm_sec': -1437999996, 'tm_hour': 9, 'tm_mday': 14, 'tm_isdst': 0, 'tm_year': 69, 'tm_mon': 10, 'tm_yday': 317, 'tm_wday': 5, 'tm_min': 32671}
```

I imagine that maybe python handles when you don't pass them in somewhat similar but I did not look at the source yet so maybe someone more experienced in `c` will confirm.

If you try to pass less than 9 elements to `time.time_struct` you will get an error which somewhat confirms what I thought:

```
In [60]: import time  
In [61]: struct = time.struct_time((2015, 6, 18))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-ee40483c37d4> in <module>()
----> 1 struct = time.struct_time((2015, 6, 18))

TypeError: time.struct_time() takes a 9-sequence (3-sequence given)
```

You must pass a sequence of 9 elements:

```
In [63]: struct = time.struct_time((2015, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))    
In [64]: struct
Out[65]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=0, tm_isdst=0)
```

Anyway with the changes you get the same behaviour in both:

```
In [16]: import pandas as pd

In [17]: import numpy as np

In [18]: test = pd.DataFrame({'date_text' : ["2015-05-18" for i in range(3)]}, dtype=np.uint32)

In [19]: apply_epoch_date_c(test['date_text'].values)
Out[19]: array([1431903600, 1431903600, 1431903600], dtype=uint32)

In [20]: apply_epoch_date_py(test['date_text'].values)
Out[20]: array([1431903600, 1431903600, 1431903600], dtype=uint32)
```

Some tests on every date since 1970-1-1 shows both return the same timestamps:

```
In [55]: from datetime import datetime, timedelta

In [56]: tests = np.array([(datetime.strptime("1970-1-1","%Y-%m-%d")+timedelta(i)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in range(16604)])

In [57]: a = apply_epoch_date_c( tests)

In [58]: b = apply_epoch_date_py( tests)

In [59]: for d1,d2 in zip(a,b):
             assert d1 == d1
   ....:     

In [60]:
```

Timing both implementations the cython code seems to indeed be quite a bit more efficient:

```
In [21]: timeit apply_epoch_date_py(test['date_text'].values)
10000 loops, best of 3: 73 µs per loop

In [22]: timeit apply_epoch_date_c(test['date_text'].values)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple pure pandas method of doing this. Dates are stored natively as i8 (in ns since epoch).

```
In [30]: df = DataFrame({'date_text':["2015-05-18" for i in range(int(10e6))]}, dtype=np.uint32)

In [31]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10000000 entries, 0 to 9999999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
date_text    object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 152.6+ MB

In [32]: pd.to_datetime(df['date_text'],infer_datetime_format=True, box=False).values.view('i8')/10**9
Out[32]: 
array([1431907200, 1431907200, 1431907200, ..., 1431907200, 1431907200,
       1431907200])

In [33]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date_text'],infer_datetime_format=True, box=False).values.view('i8')/10**9
1 loops, best of 3: 1.96 s per loop
```

Comment: you could write `int(1e9)` as `10**9`. Probably the most time consuming operation is converting from a string to a date/time object.

Comment: yep, even with the ``infer_datetime_format=True`` which caches the formatting. And the conversions are already in c, it is most of this. (Not this is a very general ISO parser, handles tz, odd formats and such).

Comment: @Jeff thanks for this. I accepted Padraic's answer as it was closest to the question I asked (what was wrong with the function I wrote) however this method is better and simpler than the Cython solution. I have added a performance plot to the question which shows how quick this method is.  Interestingly if you give pandas the format it slows down spending most of it's time in array_strp_time. I'm not sure how inferring the format is faster than being told what it is in the first place.

Comment: ``infer_datetime_format`` first infers (e.g. guesses), then caches the actual format. If you have repeated non-ISO dates it will help a lot. Since you have an ISO date it doesn't make much difference (as the parser is in c anyhow).

Comment: Yes that is what I would've thought too. But the performance difference between supplying a format and letting pandas infer one is significant.

Comment: .... (as you can see in the performance plot I put in the question edit). Supplying the format is much slower because the 1 call made to `pandas.tslib.array_strptime` is slow.

Comment: yes this has to do entirely with regex matching versus known c string parsing